# how to start a LinkedList with Arrays.asList()

Tags: java

I am trying to create a LinkedList

```
LinkedList<String> cities=  Arrays.asList("NY","LA","Seattle","San francisco");
```

which gives a compiler error because Arrays.asList returns a List<String>

I know that I could create first a List<String> and then create the linked list passing to the firs list to constructor. e.g

```
List<String> cities=  Arrays.asList("NY","LA","Seattle","San francisco");
LinkedList<String> linkedCities = new LinkedList<>(cities);
```

how would I do it with Arrays.asList or any other method, to avoid  having two lists in memory ?

Comment: You can't do this using `Arrays.asList(...)` directly.

Comment: @Leo [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) isn't going to implement any LinkedList return type, but returns a generic `List<T>`. Can you provide more inputs on how this list is generated? If you want to avoid 2 lists in memory, we can then think of creating a linkedlist during the generation of the list data

Comment: If you want to do it without using an additional variable, you could do `LinkedList<String> cities = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(...))`.

Comment: What are you trying to do. Why do you need a LinkedList?

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari I am trying to extend my knowledge on how to initialize a LinkedList collection , I found  Arrays.asList() a very easy way to start a List, so  I was wondering if could get something similar for LinkedList

Comment: The reason I ask is because one of the main purposes of data structures like LinkedList is to be dynamic (ie you can add, remove entries and the size of the collection can change). `Arrays.AsList` list totally defeats the purpose of that. It doesn't allow you update the collection size.

Answer (score 5):

For the record, you don't actually have two lists in memory. `Arrays.asList()` is just a wrapper around the passed array. But if you want to avoid the wrapper, you can construct an empty list and then populate it with a single [`Collections.addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-):

```
LinkedList<String> cities = new LinkedList<>();
Collections.addAll(cities, "NY", "LA", "Seattle", "San francisco");
```

Comment: according to the JDK code , the new linked list is filled up, so I do not think is just a wrapper. A new Node object is created per every object in the previous list : https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ca93399af103384e750dabf3abcc6e8392bcf3f4/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#L428

Comment: I was talking about `Arrays.asList()`.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Your call to `Arrays.asList` does not produce a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) object. Square peg, round hole.

So either change your declared variable to [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) instead of `LinkedList`, or explicitly create a `LinkedList` via its constructor.

Either this:

```java
List< String > list = Arrays.asList( "NY" , "LA" , "Seattle" , "San Francisco" ) ;
```

… or this:

```java
LinkedList< String > list = 
        new LinkedList <>(
                List.of( "NY" , "LA" , "Seattle" , "San Francisco" )
        );
```

## Details

To quote the Javadoc of [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

This sounds a lot like an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), but the object returned by `Arrays.asList` is *not* an `ArrayList`, well, not a `java.util.ArrayList`. What you get is an instance of a private static class confusingly named `ArrayList`, nested in `Arrays` class. See [source code in OpenJDK](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java).

Here is a demo.

```java
List < String > list = Arrays.asList( "NY" , "LA" , "Seattle" , "San francisco" );
String className = list.getClass().getName();

String javaUtilArrayListClassName = new ArrayList < String >().getClass().getName();
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/c3feKp).

```
list = [NY, LA, Seattle, San francisco]
className = java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
javaUtilArrayListClassName = java.util.ArrayList
```

If you want an `ArrayList` whole contents are copied from an array, pass to the constructor.

```java
ArrayList < String > arrayList = new ArrayList <>( Arrays.asList( "NY" , "LA" , "Seattle" , "San francisco" ) );
```

You asked:

> I am trying to create a LinkedList

and

> avoid having two lists in memory ?

In modern Java, the simplest way to create a mutable `LinkedList` using literal syntax is to create a list via `List.of`, to be passed to constructor of `LinkedList`.

```java
LinkedList < String > linkedList =
        new LinkedList <>(
                List.of( "NY" , "LA" , "Seattle" , "San Francisco" )
        );
```